# Why Attribute name length in QGIS is limited to 10 characters?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, length

In QGIS software, a vector layer has `"attribute"` but the name length is limited to only 10 Characters.

Is there any method to name an `"attribute"` to a longer name? (e.g. attribute name "**building name**" becomes "**building n**")

[image: example1]

My layer define dialog window is as below

[image: example2]

Comment: Is your layer a shapefile by any chance?

Comment: Yes! My layer is a shapefile

Comment: have this problem been solved.
looking for the solution too. Gregor

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159582)

Answer (score 18):

This is a (bad) limitation of the ESRI Shapefile format.

Not much you can do with it but change the underlying format, maybe try SpatiaLite.

Comment: Just for clarity, the limitation is directly tied to the [DBF file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase#File_formats), which the shapefile format happens to implement. As stated above, if you need/want longer file names, you'll need to choose a different storage format.