# QGIS Saving selected features with wrong data attribute column names

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Following the thread here:

[Creating new layer from selection in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/creating-new-layer-from-selection-in-qgis/26199)

I did a great job, extracting my items from the layer by type and saving them as the separate layer.

Unfortunately the problem is in data attribute table, which results wrong column naming. I though, that since every column is copied it will come in a good naming too.
See below what is the problem:

[image]

The first three columns have a proper name, whereas the rest one is wrong. It's assigned some weird name derivative from one of the columns and then copied across the entire table. Is there any way to fix it? I want to have all the columns copied/exported correctly.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356933/attribute-field-names-truncation-when-creating-shapefiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESRI Shapefiles truncate field names to 10 characters in length. You will either need to export to a different format that allows longer field names, or just rename them to something shorter and clearer.

As @user30184 points out, there is a answer to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/356933/129235) here which explains the truncation logic

Comment: That would make sense. If I remove the "M_Chambers_" section everything comes fine pretty much. Thanks for hint!